# Helly's Selection Principle

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I'm reading about Functions of Bounded Variation in Carother's Real Analysis and trying to prove the following:

> **Helly's Selection Theorem:**
>
> Let ($f_n$) be a uniformly bounded sequence of real-valued functions defined on a set X, and let D be any countable subset of X. Then, there is a subsequence of ($f_n)$ that converges pointwise on D.

By uniformly boundedness of $(f_{n})$ on X, we have that $(f_{n}(x_{1}))$ is bounded in $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore, we can contain $(f_{n}(x_{1}))$ in some compact interval in $\mathbb{R}$. By compactness, we know that any subsequence has a convergent subsequence. Hence, there exists a subsequence $(f_{n}^{(1)}(x_{1}))$ that converges. Similarly, by uniform boundedness of $(f_{n}^{1})$, we can pass to a subsequence $(f_{n}^{(2)}(x_{2}))$ that converges. By our way of construction $(f_{n}^{(2)})$ $\subseteq$ $(f_{n}^{(1)})$, therefore $(f_{n}^{(2)}(x_{2}))$ and $(f_{n}^{(2)}(x_{1}))$ both converge. We can continue this process to obtain a subsequence $(f_{n}^{(m)})$ $\subseteq$ $(f_{n})$ such that $(f_{n}^{(m)}(x_{i}))$ converges for $i = 1, 2, 3, ...$. We now have a subsequence $(f_{n}^{(m)})$ $\subseteq$ $(f_{n})$ that converges for all $x$ $\in$ $D$.

**This is the part of the proof I get confused at...**

However, instead of using this subsequence we takes the diagonal of all the constructed subsequences $(f_{n}^{(n)}(x_{k}))_{n=1}^{\infty}$ to obtain a subsequence convergent for all $x$ $\in$ $D$. Why we need to go through this diagonalization process? Furthermore, it isn't obvious to me that this "diagonal" subsequence converges for all $x$ $\in$ $D$. If someone could explain this to me that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: 'We now have a subsequence $(f_n^{(m)}) ...'$ doesn't make sense. You don't have a subsequence yet.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thank you for your reply. Yes, that was an error. What I should have said is the following: "We now have a subsequence $(f_{n}^{(m)})$ $\subseteq$ $(f_{n})$ such that $(f_{n}^{(m)}(x_{i}))$ for all $i$ $\leq$ $m$. Were you trying to illustrate I needed to evaluate the function at $x$ to say that it converges for all $x$ $\in$ $D$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By construction a subsequence $\{f_n^{(m)}(x_i)\}_{n\ge 1}$ converges for each $i\le m$. "Diagonalization" is used to get a sequence that converges for all $i\ge 1$. For fixed $i$, the tail of the diagonal sequence $\{f_n^{(n)}(x_i)\}_{n\ge i}$ is a subsequence of $\{f_n^{(i)}(x_i)\}_{n\ge 1}$ which is convergent (*by construction*).

Comment: fantastic thank you!